# Unsure why the script skips the elif statement inside a while loop - Python

Tags: python

first post, sorry if it doesn't fit the criteria or if there are similar questions. I googled before posting here and was not able to find anything about this. I'm learning python and created a very basic rock, paper, scissors game. I wanted the script to ask the user if he wants to replay the game at the end and I looked up how to do so, as I was stumped.

The script below, more specifically the while loop completely skips the elif statement and regardless if I type Y or y, it just says "ciaox" and ends. If it do it the other way around, it skips the elif statement and just restarts the game anyway.

Help would be appreciated.

```
import random

def game():

    sl = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    us = input("Rock, paper, scissors?: ")
    sl.remove(us)
    pcs = random.choice(sl)

    if us == "rock" and pcs == "paper":
        print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You lose.")
    elif us == "rock" and pcs == "scissors":
        print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You win.")
    if us == "paper" and pcs == "rock":
       print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You win.")
    elif us == "paper" and pcs == "scissors":
        print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You lose.")
    if us == "scissors" and pcs == "rock":
        print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You lose.")
    elif us == "scissors" and pcs == "paper":
        print("You chose " + us + ". PC chose " + pcs + ". You win.")

while True:
    game()
    replay = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N ")
    if replay == "N" or "n":
        print ("ciaox")
        break
    elif replay == "Y" or "y":
        game()
```

Comment: `or "n"` will cause it to always evaluate to true.

Comment: change to `if replay == "N" or replay == "n":` and `elif replay == "Y" or  replay == "y":`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. Can you elaborate, please? I am a newbie and would like to learn as much as I can.

Comment: That evaluates similar to `if (replay == 'N') or ('n'):` where the latter will always be `True` since any non-empty string is truthy. You want `if replay in 'Nn':` or `if replay.lower() == 'n'` or something like that

Comment: change to `replay = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N ").upper()`. Then you can remove the `or "n"` and the `or "y"` from the conditional statements

Comment: Python won't understand that you mean if replay is equal to N or n. You have to tell it explicitly each time like this `if replay == "N" or replay == "n"`

Comment: Appreciate it a lot, guys. Thank you, honestly. Much love.